# Python regex to remove urls and domain names in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex to remove every url or domain name from a string, so that:

```
string='this is my content domain.com more content http://domain2.org/content and more content domain.net/page'
```

becomes

```
'this is my content more content and more content'
```

Removing the most common tlds is enough for me, so I tried

```
string = re.sub(r'\w+(.net|.com|.org|.info|.edu|.gov|.uk|.de|.ca|.jp|.fr|.au|.us|.ru|.ch|.it|.nel|.se|.no|.es|.mil)\s?','',string)
```

but this is removing too much stuff and not only urls. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Sure, `.` matches any char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should escape all those dots, or better yet, move the dot outside the group and escape it once, also you could capture from not-space until not space, like this:

```
re.sub(r'[\S]+\.(net|com|org|info|edu|gov|uk|de|ca|jp|fr|au|us|ru|ch|it|nel|se|no|es|mil)[\S]*\s?','',string)
```

the following:
`'this is my content domain.com more content http://domain2.org/content and more content domain.net/page thingynet stuffocom'`
becomes:

```
'this is my content more content and more content thingynet stuffocom'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution:

```
import re
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
pattern = r"[^\s]*\.(com|org|net)\S*"
result = re.sub(pattern, '', content)
print(result)
```

Input:

```
this is my content domain.com more content http://domain2.org/content and more content domain.net/page' and https://www.foo.com/page.php
```

Output:

```
this is my content  more content  and more content  and
```